# Linode Fedora shows an incorrect time

Tags: fedora, time, linode, timezone

My fedora 17 linode VPS shows an incorrect time.

The current real time in Dublin is 15:13 but my linode shows the time below which is out by 3 hours and 45 minutes:

```
cg@lin:~$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb  6 11:26 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Eire
cg@lin:~$ date
Wed Feb  6 11:28:49 GMT 2013
```

Is there an additional step in setting the timezone in Fedora that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have NTP installed, configured and turned on.

```
sudo yum install ntp
sudo systemctl start ntpd.service 
sudo systemctl enable ntpd.service
```

Comment: Hmmm....how does this set the timezone which was the original question.  It does set the time properly but does not change the timezone.

Comment: The timezone is correct, compared to system time, he's asking why system time is not correct, ntp will set the system time correctly, and the localtime will adjust that to his timezone..